# Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined in doing a math calculation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to do a math but I am having this data not defined issue.

[image]

here's the complete script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    fetch_loan_interest();
    function fetch_loan_interest(query = '')
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('live_search.viewInterest') }}",
            method:'GET',
            data:{query:query},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#label_initial').text(data.label_initial);
                $('#interest_initial').text('Addition '+data.interest_initial+'% interest');
                $('#trigger_day_count_initial').text(data.trigger_day_count_initial);      
            }
        })
    }

    $(document).on('change', '#loan_duration_id', function(){
        var query = $(this).val();
        fetch_loan_interest(query);       
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', '#req_amount', function(){
        var req_amount = $(this).val();
        var reqAmountWithInterest = interest_initial; 
        $("#req_amount_text").text(req_amount);

        // var reqAmountWithInterest = data.interest_initial;
        var reqAmountWithInterest = req_amount * data.interest_initial;
        $("#reqAmountWithInterest").text(reqAmountWithInterest);


    });

  // if(req_amount > 0) {   
  // }
});
</script>
```

i can able to display this part
[image]

but when I am trying to do a math calculation,

```
var reqAmountWithInterest = req_amount * data.interest_initial;
```

that uncaught issue is appearing.

can you help me? thanks in advance!

Comment: In your case you are wanting to use `data` but it's out of scope. You could define a `var` outside of the `fetch_loan_interest` function and then assign it to 'data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So its saying data is not defined. because it is not defined meaning it's out of scope

```
function fetch_loan_interest(query = '') {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('live_search.viewInterest') }}",
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            query: query
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) // <- Data is defined there and you can access it within this function block.
        {
            $('#label_initial').text(data.label_initial);
            $('#interest_initial').text('Addition ' + data.interest_initial + '% interest');
            $('#trigger_day_count_initial').text(data.trigger_day_count_initial);
        }
    })
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#req_amount', function () {
    var req_amount = $(this).val();
    var reqAmountWithInterest = interest_initial;
    $("#req_amount_text").text(req_amount);
    // var reqAmountWithInterest = data.interest_initial;
    var reqAmountWithInterest = req_amount * data.interest_initial; // Data is not defined in this scope and this block is not inside the ajax
    // response function block so you wont be able to access data here
    $("#reqAmountWithInterest").text(reqAmountWithInterest);
});
```

If your intent is to initialize the amount from a response from your ajax request you should put this `var reqAmountWithInterest = req_amount * data.interest_initial;`
In the other function the one that does have data defined. 
Another possibility is to define an outer variable in the outer scope and assign data to that variable. in other word here for example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myFutureData = null
```

and then on your success function:

```
function fetch_loan_interest(query = '') {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('live_search.viewInterest') }}",
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            query: query
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) // <- Data is defined there and you can access it within this function block.
        {
            $('#label_initial').text(data.label_initial);
            $('#interest_initial').text('Addition ' + data.interest_initial + '% interest');
            $('#trigger_day_count_initial').text(data.trigger_day_count_initial);
            myFutureData = data;
        }
    });
}
```

note that data will be available on `myFutureData` once the success function is ran. So if your `keyup` event happens before the success function is called you won't get what you want.

The cleanest option in my opinion would be to use a promise:

```
function fetch_loan_interest(query = '') {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('live_search.viewInterest') }}",
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            query: query
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) // <- Data is defined there and you can access it within this function block.
        {
            $('#label_initial').text(data.label_initial);
            $('#interest_initial').text('Addition ' + data.interest_initial + '% interest');
            $('#trigger_day_count_initial').text(data.trigger_day_count_initial);
            myFutureData = data;
        }
    });
}
```

Now in `responsePromise` you have a Promise object that hold your data so you could do :

```
myPromise.done(function (data) {
    $('#label_initial').text(data.label_initial);
    $('#interest_initial').text('Addition ' + data.interest_initial + '% interest');
    $('#trigger_day_count_initial').text(data.trigger_day_count_initial);
});
```

And the same idea for your event. since your promise would be in scope. and the done assures you have the data in there.

Hope it helps